# Boost::Test -- generation of Main()?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost-test

I'm a bit confused on setting up the boost test library. Here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE pevUnitTest
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( TesterTest )
{
    BOOST_CHECK(true);
}
```

My compiler generates the wonderfully useful error message:

```
1>MSVCRTD.lib(wcrtexe.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _wmain referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup
1>C:\Users\Billy\Documents\Visual Studio 10\Projects\pevFind\Debug\pevUnitTest.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

It seems that the Boost::Test library is not generating a main() function -- I was under the impression it does this whenever `BOOST_TEST_MODULE` is defined. But ... the linker error continues.

Any ideas?

Billy3

EDIT: Here's my code to work around the bug described in the correct answer below:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE pevUnitTests
#ifndef _UNICODE
#define BOOST_TEST_MAIN
#endif
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

#ifdef _UNICODE

int _tmain(int argc, wchar_t * argv[])
{
    char ** utf8Lines;
    int returnValue;

    //Allocate enough pointers to hold the # of command items (+1 for a null line on the end)
    utf8Lines = new char* [argc + 1];

    //Put the null line on the end (Ansi stuff...)
    utf8Lines[argc] = new char[1];
    utf8Lines[argc][0] = NULL;

    //Convert commands into UTF8 for non wide character supporting boost library
    for(unsigned int idx = 0; idx < argc; idx++)
    {
        int convertedLength;
        convertedLength = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, NULL, argv[idx], -1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if (convertedLength == 0)
            return GetLastError();
        utf8Lines[idx] = new char[convertedLength]; // WideCharToMultiByte handles null term issues
        WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, NULL, argv[idx], -1, utf8Lines[idx], convertedLength, NULL, NULL);
    }

    //From boost::test's main()
    returnValue = ::boost::unit_test::unit_test_main( &init_unit_test, argc, utf8Lines );
    //End from boost::test's main()

    //Clean up our mess
    for(unsigned int idx = 0; idx < argc + 1; idx++)
        delete [] utf8Lines[idx];
    delete [] utf8Lines;

    return returnValue;
}

#endif

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( TesterTest )
{
    BOOST_CHECK(false);
}
```

Hope that's helpful to someone.

Billy3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're using the VC10 beta.

It has a fun little bug where, when Unicode is enabled, it requires the entry point to be `wmain`, not `main`. (Older versions allowed you to use both `wmain` and `main` in those cases).

Of course this will be fixed in the next beta, but until then, well, it's a problem. :)

You can either downgrade to VC9, disable Unicode, or try manually setting the entry point to `main` in project properties.

Another thing that *might* work is if you define your own wmain stub, which calls main. I'm pretty sure this is technically undefined behavior, but as a workaround for a compiler bug in an unreleased compiler it might do the trick.

Comment: Yup -- that's it. The strange thing is --- I'm not using VC10 -- I've set the toolchain to use VS2008 -- I'm only using VS2010 for it's editor. Thank you for your psychic debugging. I'm working on the last option now and will post here when it's done. (App is unicode -- no test is worth it in ANSI mode)

Comment: In my case (VC++ 2008, Windows CE console application) it was easier just to change the Entry Point linker option from mainWCRTStartup to mainCRTStartup.